# User login without username, only password

Tags: login, password, membership, username

Is it possible to modify WP so that only password is needed to login? We have members who have unique membership number and we would like them to be able to log in using only the membership number. The content is not critical so it would be fine to use only that number.

Other option would be to protect page so that it could be accessed with multiple passwords, but could not find a solution for that either.

Comment: Sorry, but this sounds very insecure and easily hacked.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the obvious answer, but why not use the users membership number as their username?

Then all you need to do is change the wording on the login page.

Good luck

David

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically you can't. Leaving aside the fact that this doesn't sound very secure, maybe you can implement some workaround like having the usernames also set to the member ship number. Or hack the login page to prepopulate the username. Or maybe even hide that input box from the page.

Answer (score -1):

not sure if it makes sense, but here's what i would do.

1. Define same password for every user.
2. On the login widget or page hide password input and pre define the value.
3. When user enters the correct username and hit enter, it's a login.